# How to get current date and time in android without Internet and without from location

Tags: android, time

I want to get the current date and time from android device without Internet and without its location.

I've tried to get the current time and date by `LocationManager` class but it provide the time before 2 hours not accurate.

My Code 1 -

```
  LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Location location=locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(location!=null){
        long time = location.getTime();

        Log.e("Time",     getDate(time, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS")+"");

    }else{
        Log.e("Time", "Location is null");
    }
```

Permission -

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

My Current time is 19/08/2019 12:02:00.500
But the output is

```
E/Time: 19/08/2019 09:46:43.500
```

My Code 2-

```
String s1= android.provider.Settings.System.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
       android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME);
if (s1.contentEquals("0")) {
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(
            this.getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, "1");
}
Date d1= new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Log.e("finalvalue", d1.toString());
```

But for this solution i have to add the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Which can only be add for system apps.

My Code 3-

```
Log.e("Time",     getDate(System.currentTimeMillis(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS")+"");
```

It is also showing the current date and time but if user change the device date and time then it will show the wrong date and time. Because it totally depends on the device date and time.

Is it possible to get the accurate current date and time without internet and location.

Comment: what do you mean without location ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody without location means without using LocationManager class because it is giving wrong time.

Comment: you can use System.currenttimemillis() and parse in date object.

Comment: why not just make a new Date() ?

Comment: you have to add the location permission in manifest its manditory

Comment: @PratikMohanraoGondil Yes permission is added to manifest. I have edited the question.

Comment: @ChandanSharma If the user will change the device date and time then it will not work

Comment: Did you try using `java.time` / `java.utils` for that purpose? And one more question, are you using real device or emulator to test that? Because the trick could be in the device local time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current time in millis from system with

```
Long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And parse it to date format you want.

```
String date = DateUtils.convertTimestampToStringDate(millis, this);
```

And the class date utils

```
public class DateUtils {

private static final String TAG = "DateUtils";
public static String convertTimestampToStringDate(long timestamp, Context context){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    String df = "d MMM yyyy";
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(df, getCurrentLocale(context));
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    Log.d(TAG, "convertTimestampToStringDate: "+dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
    return dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
}


private static Locale getCurrentLocale(Context contexr) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return contexr.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
    } else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        return contexr.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    }
}
```

}